# How do I find a list of beans for a given Spring Boot class/package?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, javabeans

I am currently working with [Spring Boot](http://spring.io) with a number of starter packs, such as the web MVC framework, Thymeleaf templates and security.

Each of these packages have a lot of different configuration options. I have mainly been using the source from the Auto-configuration package to figure out which beans need to be wired up and how to do that.

However, Is there any easy way to find a list of expected beans/classes that are needed by a given Spring package?

Comment: Due to the various possible configurations, the IDE will not tell you all the required dependencies. It is a matter of looking at [Spring's Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) and running the project until you get something working.

Answer (score 0):

To view the beans you can you spring boot actuator

To Enable actuator, you can simply add the actuator starter dependency to your project.

For Gradle

```
compile("'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.3.1.RELEASE'
")
```

For Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You can skip the version if you are using spring boot parent pom

Now you can rebuild your application make get request to `http://server:port/beans` if local and port is 8080 then

```
http://localhost:8080/beans
```

If you want to access using CURL command line tool you can

```
curl http://localhost:8080/beans
```

For more information visit

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html